# Change free windows phone app to paid one

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I have an application in the windows phone marketplace which is ad supported (free to download) and requires an internet connection to work (to download some data from a web service).

Now that web service allows me to download that data as a XML and use it. Hence I would now like to release a paid version of that app which is without ads and works offline. Can I just release an update to my existing app and add all the new features and make it paid and under the trial section put the old ad supported one?

Also will my current users be able to update to the new one (i.e. the one without ads) without having to paid. (Because initially they downloaded the free one, i.e app purchased for $0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track. Make an updated version of your app that uses ads for the trial version and removes them when the app is purchased. When you submit the update, add a price and check the Allow Trial checkbox. That's all there is to it.

One thing to note: When you do this, your app will appear in the paid apps section of the Marketplace, which will probably cause your downloads to drop significantly. I converted a free app to paid with free unlimited trial with ads like you're describing and my numbers dropped a lot. I am making about the same from purchases that I was making with the ads, though, so it's been OK from that perspective.

I'm not sure what will happen to existing users, although I suspect they will be updated and then run in trial mode with the ads.

Comment: Interesting point about the change from free to paid dropping downloads. I guess for you there a smaller support base required and you can improve on quality for the app?!

Comment: This no longer seems to be true (SEP 2012).  You can't add a price, the field is greyed out.

Comment: @JasonShort have you entered your payment bank account or PayPal details? The drop down was greyed out for me until after I entered my bank account payment info.

Comment: Can anyone answer the part about what happens to existing users? Will they update for free to the adless version having never paid; will they be charged to update and would they be able to choose not to upgrade and continue with the old ad-supported version?